# How to create blob creatObjectURL using firebasestorage href

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a firebase storage link and I am trying to create a blob URL using the firebase storage href. is it possible to fetch content from firebase and create a blob URL in react? Or is there a better way of creating a blob URL using firebase storage href? can someone please advise how to proceed?

Comment: What do you want to do with the blob URL? Why does it have to be a blob URL?

Comment: I want to display video file using that URL. with regular src link, it directly references the storage. which allows another user to look up the src and access the video outside the site or download it. i want to prevent that from happening

Comment: Then a blob URI won't help you. In order to get a blob URI pointing to the media, you need to first fetch that media to a Blob. If someone wants to download your media, they can just look at their network tab and see where the Blob as been fetched from => no security at all. The only way to prevent your users to download your media for other uses than in your website are DRMs.